# Insert into mssql

Tags: sql-server, insert

I have 2 tables in an mssql database, `horse_data` and `trainer_data`. The horse_data has the following columns:-

`horse_id, horse_name, horse_nationality, horse_yof, horse_sex,    horse_sire, horse_dam, horse_trainer_id`,

and trainer_data's columns are :- 
 `trainer_id, 
trainer_name`,

There is a foreign key relationship between trainer_id and horse_trainer_id.

How can I insert an new record into the horse_data table, and instead of entering an int for the value of horse_trainer_id enter the name of a trainer and then have the insert query look up the value in the trainer_data and insert the correct trainer_id into horse_trainer_id column of the horse_data table?

Comment: I can do. Ultimately it will be via a winforms app but first I just want to learn how to do it in mssql writing the query in the mssql design studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO horse_data (horse_id, horse_name, horse_nationality, 
                        horse_yof, horse_sex, horse_sire, horse_dam, horse_trainer_id)
VALUES (horse_id, horse_name, horse_nationality, horse_yof, 
        horse_sex, horse_sire, horse_dam, 
        (SELECT TOP 1 trainer_id FROM  trainer_data WHERE trainer_name = 'name'))
```

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a dream. Thank you.